# How to make a no code platform using tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drag-and-drop, desktop-application

I am planning to make a desktop application based on no code platform, drag and drop elements and create a web page or form without coding. It will be similar to canva, UI will have two sections:-

1. Widget section: list of widgets like text box, submit button, cancel button, etc. with proper logic will be present on one side of app.
2. white space area: user can drag and drop widgets here, to develop a web page or web form. And somewhere in background the respective code will get generated. Like if user placed one button over white space then in background the code for button is saved, and after designing the web page/form user can simply download the auto generated code of the same.

My Q is, is it possible to create such application in tinker and what workflow should I adopt to encounter it?

Comment: Maybe edit your title a bit, when I first read it sounded like it was one of the posts where its just "i want to do something but have no clue, tell me how", when you actually have two well defined questions at the end there, and are asking for help that while a bit open ended, is much better than "do my work for me", so I dont want you to lose answerers because of that first impression.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, though it will require a lot of work.